# Lucene - Searching several terms in different fields

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, lucene.net

I have a Lucene index which populates from a database. I store/index some fields and then add a FullText field in which I index the contents of all the other fields, so I can do a general search.

Now let's say I have a document with the following two fields:
fld1 - "Samsung releases a new 22'' LCD screen"
fld2 - "Sony Ericsson phone's batteries explode"

If an user does a "Samsung phone", he probably just wants news about samsung phones, not a document with info about a samsung screen and a sony phone, but searching by the FullText field, I will get this as a valid result. 
Is there a nice way to handle this?

I've thought of indexing with some separator and the doing a SpanNotQuery, so the FullText field would have this contents:
"Samsung releases a new 22'' LCD screen MYLUCENESEPARATOR Sony Ericsson phone's batteries explode" and then doing a SpanNotQuery with MYLUCENESEPARATOR as the non-spanning term.

Is this a good solution? Does it scale well with more than two terms? I fear it would be a performance killer. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of fields is limited you can put the two description strings in two different fields. Then you can use [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) to search on these fields. Since these are two separate fields, the document will match only if both the terms appear in a single field with AND operator.

Let's take your example.
fld1 - "Samsung releases a new 22'' LCD screen" 
fld2 - "Sony Ericsson phone's batteries explode"

If these are indexed in separate fields fld1 & fld2, your query becomes

```
(+fld1:samsung +fld1:phone) (+fld2:samsung +fld2:phone)
```

Multifield query helps you to construct such queries easily so that you don't need to repeat a query for multiple fields.

Comment: I accepted your answer but forgot to vote up. Perhaps a bit late, but just did it now :-)